# pySerial dictionary confusion

Tags: python, pyserial

PySerial version 3.4

I trying to figure out how to use the inWaiting property. So I printed out what is available:

```
>>> import serial

>>> ser = serial.Serial(...intialization stuff)

>>> print (serial.Serial.__dict__.keys())
dict_keys(['__module__', '__doc__', 'open', '_reconfigure_port', 'close', 'in_waiting', 'read', 'cancel_read', 'cancel_write', 'write', 'flush', 'reset_input_buffer', 'reset_output_buffer', 'send_break', '_update_break_state', '_update_rts_state', '_update_dtr_state', 'cts', 'dsr', 'ri', 'cd', 'out_waiting', 'fileno', 'set_input_flow_control', 'set_output_flow_control', 'nonblocking', '__abstractmethods__', '_abc_impl'])
```

ah ok there is the 'in_waiting' I was looking for.  But I was still having problems so I did this:

```
>>> print (ser.__dict__.keys())
dict_keys(['is_open', 'portstr', 'name', '_port', '_baudrate', '_bytesize', '_parity', '_stopbits', '_timeout', '_write_timeout', '_xonxoff', '_rtscts', '_dsrdtr', '_inter_byte_timeout', '_rs485_mode', '_rts_state', '_dtr_state', '_break_state', '_exclusive', 'fd', 'pipe_abort_read_r', 'pipe_abort_read_w', 'pipe_abort_write_r', 'pipe_abort_write_w'])
```

I'm a python newbie and I fully expected 'ser' to inherit (if that is the right term) the dictionary of serial.Serial.  Obviously I'm wrong.

Can someone help me understand?

By the way it seems that

```
ser.inWaiting()
```

is the only thing that works but I expected (based on the serial.Serial dictionary) to use:

```
ser.in_waiting
```

Pretty clueless about that too. I'm looking for learning here :)

Comment: The things you see in `ser.__dict__.keys()` are attributes that have explicitly been set on your instance of `Serial` - this does *not* include methods that are inherited from the class.  `ser.in_waiting` should have worked, given that you're using a PySerial version of 3.0 or later - what exactly was the error when you tried?

Comment: omg. I'll tell you (admit) what I did.  I used: .inwaiting, .inWaiting, in_Waiting, in_waiting(), in_Waiting(), but never for some reason, 'in_waiting'.